Recording of 2009 lecture on Harvey Friedman's work
On December 13--20 2009 at Bristol, there was a meeting devoted to thorough dissection of Harvey Friedman's work on the foundations of mathematics and his statements claimed to be equivalent to consistency of large cardinals, organized by Andrey Bovykin. This archived page from the Bristol website contains some information, including three links to a talk given by Friedman to other mathematicians in attendance. However, none of the video links are archived. Are there any copies of this talk or its materials still in circulation?

The link is to Andrey Bovykin's (former) personal webspace at Bristol. If anybody has kept a copy, it's likely to be him. Have you tried contacting him? You can find his Gmail address by searching for him at UFBA.

I was there.  While my memory is not perfect, I can answer general questions.

@JeremyRickard At the time of posting this question I was only aware of his PDMI address, which I expected to be inactive. Thank you for pointing me to a more current address, I will see if I hear back!

@SamSanders Thank you for commenting! Do you know if Friedman's unprovability proofs involved new machinery not widely known, or if they consisted of standard machinery? (I have this question because as far as I am aware, none of the unprovability proofs have been reproduced, and am curious about whether it is due to necessary machinery remaining unpublished or not.)

@C7X According to his website, Harvey Friedman presented a variant of this talk: https://u.osu.edu/friedman.8/files/2014/01/UnpThms110509-q4xc2f.pdf

@SamSanders This does appear to be the talk I was asking for in the question and the one linked on the Bristol page, #223 on Friedman's list of lectures. I suppose the intention of my question was more to find recordings of #225, the details of boolean relation theory, and at the time of asking the question I did not know that these were separate events at the same meeting. Would it be too late of me to edit the question to reflect this?

So I do not think there are (full) recordings of the 50hours of the "boolean relation theory" (BRT) workgroup.  This was a concerted effort at proof-reading Harvey's book on BRT, to be found on his website and one day in print.  One of the participants found a small (fixable) error, but otherwise the results were correct.  I contributed "intuitive explanations" for the chapters, section, ... For BRT, the book on Harvey's website should explain everything.
